# Что означает это регулярное выражение?

Tags: python-2.x, импорт

```
re.split('[^a-z]')
re.split('[^a-z]')
```

Comment: Порезать второй аргумент(его у вас нет) по символам, не являющимся буквами. Останется список слов.

Comment: в дополнение к комментарию выше: не являющимися латинскими буквами нижнего регистра

Comment: спасибо большое за ответы. А как сделать так чтобы в дополнение к условию выше у меня еще убирались пробелы ??